# JSP/HTML required fields only for specific submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have table for **user** with 8 fields to complete fields via *input type="text"*. I have added to 4 fields tag *"required"*.
And 4 buttons input type="submit":

```
add
delete
edit
deactivate
```

The problem is that *"required"* field is checked for all submit buttons, but I want it to be checked only when *"add"* button is pushed. Is there any way to bind "required" field to specific button?

Answer (score 0):

Try it please.

```js
$("form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
   //console.log($(this).val());
   if($(this).val()!=="ADD"){
      $('form input[type=text]').each(function() {
         $(this).removeAttr("required");
      });
   }
   $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
   $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='nothing' method='post' name='testform'>
    <input type="text" id="name" required>
    <input type="text" id="age" required>
    <input type='submit' name='add' value='ADD' />
    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='DELETE' />
</form>
```